# Results for deleted / renamed tests still appear in Allure reports using Jenkins Allure plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins, pytest, allure

I am using the Jenkins Allure plugin to generate reports for PyTest runs.

I've noticed that if I delete a failing test from my repository, or rename a failing test, the Allure reports generated by Jenkins continue to show failures for the old tests, even though they no longer exist and did not run in the most recent job.

How do I ensure that Allure reports only contain results for tests that actually ran in the latest job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generate the results in `allure-results` directory in your root project.
Every time you run your job, those new allure results files will be generated in the Jenkins workspace. You should clean your workspace before the build starts to ensure that you are taking the last execution:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Frank Escobar's answer is correct.

I want to add that if you're using a pipeline the option in his screenshot is not available.

In that case, use the Jenkins Clear Workspace plugin https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ws-cleanup/ and create a pipeline step to clear your workspace before starting the test run.